# How to configure stream-django with DRF

Tags: django, stream, feed, stream-django

I am using stream-django to create newsfeed in my DRF project but when I am trying to add an activity I am getting this error,

> StreamApiException: GetStreamAPI404

I have properly mentioned the `STREAM_API_KEY` and `STREAM_API_SECRET`

Could you please help me, I am using stream-django for the first time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stream-django` uses the `stream-python` library which actually looks for an environment variable `LOCAL` if it finds it then it assumes that the stream server is a local server. Unfortunately, I was using `LOCAL` variable as an environment local development purpose. While digging inside the library I found it and removed it. Since then it started working as expected.